# Golang persistent channel accepting input from multiple function calls

Tags: asynchronous, go, synchronization, channel

I have a function `a`:

```
func a(input *some_type) {
    // do sth.
    b(input)
    }
```

This function gets called multiple times.
I want a function `b` to wait indefinitely for input from function `a` and perform an action when it has collected n inputs.

```
func b(input *some_type) {
    // wait until received n inputs then do sth. with all inputs
    }
```

How would I go about doing this? My first thought was to use a `sync.WaitGroup` with a channel between `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common producer-consumer problem. Use channels to wait on the input from another routine. Does something like this help?

In this particular example, you would have to call `go b(c)` again after collecting the inputs as it terminates, but you could easily wrap whatever `b` does in an infinite `for` loop. Or whatever needs to happen.

Please note that in this example, and unbuffered `channel` is used, which forces both routines to meet at the same time to "hand off" the `*Thing`. If you want the producer (`a`'s process) to not have to wait, you can use a buffered channel, which is created like so:

```
c := make(chan(*Thing, n))
```

Where `n` is the number of items the channel can store. This allows several to be queued by the producer.

https://play.golang.org/p/X14_QsSSU4

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type Thing struct {
    N int
}

func a(t *Thing, c chan (*Thing)) {
    // stuff happens. whee
    c <- t
}

func b(c chan (*Thing)) {
    things := []*Thing{}
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        t := <-c
        things = append(things, t)
        fmt.Printf("I have %d things\n", i+1)
    }
    fmt.Println("I now have 10 things! Let's roll!")
    // do stuff with your ten things
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    c := make(chan (*Thing))

    go b(c)

    // this would probably be done producer-consumer like in a go-routine
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        a(&Thing{i}, c)
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
    }
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
    fmt.Println("Program finished")
}
```